# Unable to Sent Email with Attachment using SMTP Client. Asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am tried to send an email using smtp client using .net mvc with pdf attachment (in memory attachment), its not working on Live Server.

**Please Note:** 
I am able to sent email with Attachment from my localhost. but when i deployed on Live Server (Hosted on IIS) its not working. Same Method is working without attachment on live server.

I am getting the following Exception:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:'smtp.zoho.com' at 
System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at 
System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

here by Code:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ms = new MemoryStream(PdfSharpConvert(RawFileHtml));
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new 
System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName + ".pdf";

var message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
message.Attachments.Add(attach);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
isSuccess = true;
ms.Close();
```

Here My Config for Mail

```
 <smtp from="MyFromEmail">
 <network 
    host="smtp.zoho.com"
    port="587"
    userName="MyUsername"
    password="MyPassword"
    enableSsl="true" />
</smtp>
```

Please help how to solve this problem

Thank you.

Comment: the answer seems very simple.. it cant find smtp.zoho.com you need to fix dns

Comment: its working without attachment

Comment: the error message doesnt show that - it shows the live server cannot connect to the smtp server.. if its an attachment, id expect another error, it could be the attachment types are banned on that server, but, the error you show here is bad dns.

Comment: i also try changing smtp server to smtp.gmail.com still getting same exception.

Comment: `="smtp.zoho.com>"` is not correct if you actually have that (remove the `>`)

Comment: @AlexK. it a typo error, i don't have > on my config file. thanks

Comment: try port 465 https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html#alink2

Comment: i try port 465 still not working.